# shell access enabled but still not working in whm (On Rackspace)

Tags: shell, ssh, whm, rackspace

I have the box checked for "shell access" in the package I am using on the account, yet when I try to login via ssh I am still getting the message:

Shell access is not enabled on your account!
If you need shell access please contact support.

Is there another step that needs to be taken?

The support for whm link seems to be broken at the moment, so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is no other way to control access, as i know

if you have no shell, nither panel - contact hoster technical support service or your reseller exactly as message said